# How should the final "о" in "эхо" be pronounced?

Tags: произношение

In Wiktionary I see [ə] (in full: [ˈɛxə]), but what I hear in various samples is not fully a fully reduced schwa but something more like the semi-reduced pronunciation [ɐ] of <а> and <о>, or even (in some speakers [on Forvo](https://forvo.com/word/%D1%8D%D1%85%D0%BE/#ru), for example) a short [o]. What rules apply to this situation, and to what extent does it depend on dialect or context?

I gather from [Sergey Slepov’s answer](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/21243/12497) that it is indeed semi-reduced, but I am also interested in when people use [o] rather than [ɐ]. Does this suggest anything about the speaker, e.g. where they come from, their age or their education? Or does it convey extra semantic information, e.g. about emphasis or a question? And how was it pronounced on the heavily standardised TV in the USSR?

Comment: you got it right!

Comment: Speaking about TV & USSR, *эхо* is not the most frequent word to be used by a news reader but here is a nice song from 1977: [Эхо любви](https://youtu.be/f8pop9Td1Zo) where you can hear it numerous times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. Unstressed word-final vowels are only reduced half-way.

Here is a quote from [Russian Phonetics](https://fonetica.philol.msu.ru/lena-1/vocal/v8_1.html) by Moscow State University authors:

> The following unstressed syllables undergo a weak reduction:
>
> 1. the first syllable before the stressed syllable
> 2. the word-initial syllable that starts with a vowel
> 3. the word-final open syllable

The "о" in "эхо" falls under case number 3.

The absence of reduction in "о" (as in Postscripter2's sample on Forvo) can mean that:

1. The speaker is over-pronouncing. Reasons may include trying to get across the exact spelling of a word which is probably what Postscripter2 did, quite possibly inadvertently. Teachers often get into the habit of over-pronouncing when dictating or simply reading off a sheet of paper.
2. The speaker is a native of the [Northern Russian dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Russian_dialects) which has *okanie* ([оканье](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5)) (think Vologda). Such people are quite rare these days.
3. The speaker's first language is not Russian or is influenced by another language with *okanie* e.g. Ukrainian. Most Slavic languages except for Russian have *okanie*, i.e. no reduction of "o".

See also my answer to [this very similar question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/20741/2104).

Comment: Thank-you, this covers part of my question clearly, but I was also trying to ask about the choice between [o] and [ɐ], so I have expanded my question to make that clearer. (Thanks also for translating the Russian, with which I was struggling!)

Answer (score 0):

Using heavily English-centric IPA to describe Russian pronunciation is a bad idea. In Russian phonetic analysis the word is analyzed as [эха].

Comment: Funnily enough, [Russian Wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%8D%D1%85%D0%BE) renders it as [ˈɛxə], identical to English Wiktionary. You have also not explained why some speakers use [o] rather than [ɐ].

Comment: @PJTraill I venture to assume that when the speaker looks at a written word 'эхо', he pronounces  'o' more clearly than if he spoke without seeing the letters

Comment: @PJTraill It seems Wikitionary forces English style transcription on all languages